# Cordova hybrid app- HTTP requests are very slow

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, cordova, restangular

I am building a hybrid app, with `AngularJS`, `Cordova`, `Restangular` ond client side and `Python` with `wsgiref.simple_server` on server side. I am not doing anything special, this is very simply requests like this:

```
Restangular.one('/devices').get().then(function (response) {
    viewModel.devices = Restangular.stripRestangular(response.devices);
});
```

I set `baseUrl` for `Restangular`:

```
.config(function(RestangularProvider){
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://192.168.54.102:8000/');
})
```

And when I use it on local computer with Chrome browser, everything is fast, works normal. But when I use it on Android on `Phonegap developer app` on device or install app on device with Android, it works crazy slow. It looks like it is send to server with big delay, cause it takes some time as I see debug server log on server side. It occurs also when python application with server is not in debug mode, for example when I start it normally after install on local computer. As I see some people has this problem, does anybody found a solution or a reason, which causes very slow HTTP requests in hybrid application? Thank you in advance for every answer.

Comment: I don't use angular, nor restangular, but I'm using a lot of ajax calls and websockets in my cordova apps and they are very fast.

Comment: can you try to open it on chrome on the same device where it's slow on the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are a hybrid developer, I am sure you are familiar with the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). For me on a Mac, hit cmd + option + i, or go to View -> Developer -> Developer Tools.

The really great thing about Chrome in recent history is it now works with Android WebViews too. Hybrid developers haven't always had this convenience, and had to debug essentially handcuffed using tools like [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/).

Now we can use the DevTools directly in the Chrome browser while your Android device is connected by ADB from a new tab calling [chrome://inspect](http://chrome://inspect)

[Here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) is some more detailed information on how to do this if you get stuck.

From here open up the network panel and see how long your requests are taking. If they are showing a significantly longer amount of time to load here, the issue has nothing to with Angular, Cordova, Restangular or probably even Hybrid architecture at all. I would check your network and performance elsewhere on the device.

If this is definitely not the issue, I would use the [Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) tab in the DevTools to see what is taking so long between your browser receiving the information and your device displaying it. If there is any significantly longer process taking place in between, you will see it here.